# Подчинение придаточных

Tags: грамматика

Неоднородное ли подчинение придаточных в данном предложении?
*Делай, что я скажу и когда  скажу* (делай — что? — что я скажу; делай — когда? — когда я скажу)
Верно ли? Возможно ли такое подчинение? В справочниках обыкновенно приводятся примеры неоднородного подчинения, когда главная часть находится между подчинёнными частями.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Делай, **что я скажу и когда скажу**.*

1. Это ***СПП*** с двумя  **местоименно-определительными** придаточными, союз *И*.

В таких *СПП* придаточные **определяют** местоименное указательное слово (коррелят) в главном предложении. В общем случае местоименное слово **обязательно**, но в разговорном стиле присутствует **не всегда.**

Исходный вариант: *Делай **то**, что я скажу, **и тогда**, когда (я) скажу.*

2. Местоименные слова **разные** (делай *то* и *тогда*), то есть придаточные **неоднородные**. Но их можно считать **сближенными** по позиции в предложении, по грамматике (союз ***И***) и по семантике (делай всё по-моему). Поэтому в данном предложении они будут **однородными**, запятой перед союзом *И* нет.

Comment: Благодарю! Хорошего дня! :)

Comment: Спасибо! Вы как в магазине:)   Там это дежурная фраза, но все равно приятно))  И вам хороших и новых впечатлений от жизни вообще и от этого дня в частности.

Comment: @Sharon: «_Делай, **что я скажу и когда скажу.**_ Это _**СПП**_ с двумя **местоименно-определительными** придаточными, союз И.» ❓❓❓===  МЕСТОИМЕНО-ОПРЕДЕЛИТЕЛЬНЫМИ❓❓❓

Comment: Вы не согласны? Дайте, пожалуйста, свой ответ.  Кстати, у вас было время это сделать. Уже 17 часов прошло. Я специально подождала другие ответы.  Рекомендую предварительно ознакомиться с теорией по новому учебнику Кустовой.

Comment: @Sharon: «Рекомендую предварительно ознакомиться с теорией по новому учебнику Кустовой.» === Учебник этот у меня есть. Если подскажете, на какой странице учебника придаточное типа «_(тогда), когда (я) скажу_» названо Кустовой местоименно-**определительным**, обязательно ознакомлюсь!

Comment: Зачем же я буду вам помогать и страничку искать. Сами найдете.  Ваше поведение, кстати, недружелюбно.  Критика, сокращенные слова и т.д. Все, кроме собственного ответа.  Имейте это в виду.