# Почему на этом сайте придаточное в предложении «Делай (тогда), когда я скажу» считают местоименно-определительным?

Tags: синтаксис, спп, придаточное-предложение

Побудил меня задать такой вопрос ответ (и комментарии автора ответа) на вопрос **[«Подчинение придаточных»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478912/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/478920#478920)**, в котором придаточное в предложении ***«Делай (тогда), когда я скажу»*** квалифицировано как **местоименно-определительное.**

Но можно ли это придаточное называть **местоименно-определительным**?

Я всегда считал, что местоименно-определительными (или приместоименно-определительными) называют только те придаточные, что относятся к **субстантивированному** указательному или определительному местоимению  главной части. Так говорится, к примеру, в учебнике для пед. институтов «Современный русский язык» (авторы: Р.Н. Попов, Д.П. Валькова, Л.Я. Маловицкий, А.К. Федоров), выпущенном в 1986 году.

Н.С. Валгина в «Синтаксисе современного русского языка» (1991) в разделе «Приместоименно-определительные предложения» приводит перечень определительных и указательных местоимений, выступающих в этих предложениях в качестве соотносительных слов: ***все, каждый, всякий, любой; тот, такой, таков***.

В справочнике для школ «Русский язык» М.Т. Баранова и др. (12-е изд.; 2011 г.) такие придаточные упоминаются только в разделе «Сложноподчинённые предложения с придаточными определительными»:

> К придаточным определительным близки придаточные, относящиеся к местоимениям (местоимённо-определительные). Они отвечают на вопрос **кто именно? что именно?** *Кто с пользой отечеству трудится, тот с ним легко не разлучится*…

Как видим, термин **местоименно-определительное придаточное** авторы этих (и множества других) пособий относят не ко всем предложениям **местоименно-соотносительного** структурного типа, в которых используются местоименные пары ***тот – кто; то – что; столько – сколько; там – где и др.***, а только к части из них.

Стоит отметить, что предложения с местоименной парой ***тогда – когда*** обычно в состав местоименно-соотносительных не включаются, а рассматриваются как подтип придаточных времени. ***Когда*** в таких предложениях чаще оказывается по своим свойствам ближе к союзу, чем к местоимению.

Так, Кускова Г.И. в «Синтаксисе русского языка» (2013 г.) пишет:

> Пары с обстоятельственным значением… ***постольку – поскольку*** и ***тогда – когда*** следует рассматривать как (необязательный) коррелят и **союз**.

Наверное, в каких-то случаях — как, например, в приводимом далее Кусковой примере *Встреча может произойти **там** и **тогда**, **где** и **когда** для неё возникнут подходящие условия*, в котором «сочиняются однотипные единицы, т. е. союзные слова», — придаточные в предложениях с парой ***тогда – когда*** и можно было бы характеризовать как **местоименно–соотносительные**…

Но почему на этом сайте их называют **местоименно-определительными?**…